# AC compressor replacement

Tags: ac, compressor

I replaced my AC compressor and wanted to know if I can run it without haveing the AC on.........I replaced the AC compressor myself and need to take it to get vacuumed. I wanna know if I can drive it, and if so for how long (how many miles can I run it)

Comment: Need to know what compressor model and brand it is. If it has a clutch just disconnect the clutch coil power connectors and you'll be sure it won't engage no matter what. If it is a clutchless compressor the thing is always turning when engine on and it will be damaged.

Comment: Did you just replace the ac compressor, what about the dryer and the orifice tube that are usually changed along with the compressor when it's changed out, did you oil it ?

Answer (score 0):

The AC should never engage if there is no Freon in it regardless of the climate setting in the car. Yes you can drive it, if you are paranoid disconnect the electrical connector from the compressor.

Comment: This applies for a clutch equipped compressor. If the compressor is of the clutchless type (for example the ones on VW cars) the internals are always rotating with the engine and if there's no lubrication (in nowadays automotive compressors, there is no dedicated sump and oil pump, and therefore lubrication is provided primarily by the refrigerant flow) that compressor will die in short order.